# Pass data conditonally from Ajax request to javascript index

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to pass data back in my value map, conditionally depending on boolean values in mySQL database.

I query my database and store the information in $results.  Then I build my value map using the code below.

```
//Query database
if(!$results = $link->query($sql)){
  die("Query Unsuccessful");
}

$valueMap = array();

while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $valueMap[] = array(
      'title' => $data['title'],
      'lat' => $data['lat'],
      'lng' => $data['lng'],
      'description' => $data['description'],
      'descriptionPub' => $data['descriptionPub'],
    );
}
```

As of right now I am passing all of this data and more via JSON string.    However I would like to  check the value of descriptionPub in this case to see if the data should be made public.  If it is true Id like to pass description... if false I would like to not pass description.

I tried something like

```
  if($data['descriptionPub']){
        'description' => $data['description'],
      }
```

I also tried setting a variable the data conditionally and then passing this into my value map.

```
  if($data['descriptionPub']){
        $msg = $data['description'];
      }else{
        $msg = "";
      }
      'description' => $msg,
```

But on my index page I am don't appear to get any data when implementing either of these.

Im pretty new, so I hope there is an easy way to achieve this behavior that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`?:`):

```php
while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $valueMap[] = array(
      'title' => $data['title'],
      'lat' => $data['lat'],
      'lng' => $data['lng'],
      'description' => $data['descriptionPub'] ? $data['description'] : '',
      'descriptionPub' => $data['descriptionPub']
    );
}
```

or move the logic out of the array literal:

```php
while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($data['descriptionPub']) {
        $description = $data['description'];
    } else {
        $description = '';
    }
    $valueMap[] = array(
      'title' => $data['title'],
      'lat' => $data['lat'],
      'lng' => $data['lng'],
      'description' => $description,
      'descriptionPub' => $data['descriptionPub']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary operator to solve this:

```
$valueMap[] = array(
      'title' => $data['title'],
      'lat' => $data['lat'],
      'lng' => $data['lng'],
      'description' => $data['descriptionPub'] ? $data['description'] : "",
    );
```

This will not remove the description key but will put an empty string as value, which seems exeptable to you.